# PHP script to make a dynamic image

Tags: php

I have a CMS that my freind built and I need to adjust one thing but I don't know how so please help me ...

this is my question :

I have an image in my home page , and I want the user to be able to click on this image and navigate to some website

now this website's link will be provided by the user in the CMS

I have added a textbox so that the user can write the link , and saved the link in mySQL database , but I don't know how to connect my image to this link I have ?!

Please help me

Comment: That entirely depends on what technologies the CMS is using. Is there nothing in the CMS that you can copy and remodel for your purposes?

Comment: "Please help me as fast as possible" - sure, because we're all paid staff. Avoid phrases like that, it's very rude. People here will help you as their time permits.

Comment: Sorry for rudness , My boss wants me to do it now , and I have no experience at all in php

Comment: I just have to do it so I can save my friend's ass

Comment: I don't like the way the title is neither a question nor related to this nonspecific issue. Where's the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this sounds bad idea.
There is nothing safe to let users be able to add a link.

But, to answer your question.
So, you have something like this in your user table?

```
id | username | password | avatarImage
```

then you can create a query to mySQL:

```
SELECT avatarImage FROM users WHERE link id = '89' LIMIT 0, 1
```

and then add a photo

```
<img src=" image link here " />
```

But I would have taken a look at: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php

It may be that I misunderstood you here. If so, I apologize:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I know its not safe too , but my boss knows nothing about programming and my friend is absent today ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?= $encodedurl ?>"><img src="..." /></a>
```